# Does anyone has any suggestions on WEbAii, Watin and Selenuim

Tags: watin

Please give me your valuable suggestions regarding the WebAii, Watin and Selenuim. 
Actually i have been using WebAii and its working fine for me but at the same time i have not used other frameworks to test Ajax supported web applications. 
Please share your thoughts or issues you faced while using one of these frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We used both watir, watin, and webaii and have opted for webaii because of it's predictability in dealing with AJAX.

The webaii framework is priced right :)  but it would have made some people on the team more comfortable if it had been open source.

Comment: As far my knowledge Webaii is free isn't it ?

Comment: WebAii is a FREE .NET library for web automation that supports both Firefox and Internet Explorer using one consistent API.  as taken from their web site: http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx 

Their design canvas plug in certainly isn't free.

Comment: It no longer appears to be free?  I went to find WebAii tonight and all I see is everything pointing back to WebUI Test Studio, which is $1499.

Comment: @Ryan Rumour has it that ArtOfTest was purchased by Telerik and so it may very well be that it's no longer free.  You'd have to check with Telerik http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Even after the merger with Telerik. WebAii is still free. It can be downloaded from here:
http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx